# Can I store a program on my mouse that runs when i connect it?

Tags: mouse, usb-drive

So various people around my house have been stealing my mouse and I was wondering if I could store a program on the mouse which runs whenever it's plugged in, asking you for a password. I know you can run a program stored on a computer when a device is inserted into a USB slot but that means I can't stop people using my mouse if the specific laptop he's using hasn't got the program installed.

Also, if this was possible, what language would use? I would like it to work on windows, linux and OSX to cover all bases.

Thanks for any help!